# Unit testing framework timeouts in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I'm running some unit tests for a large VB.Net application I help maintain and am running into problems with tests timing out.

The test run is set up so that there's no timeout limit on the overall test run, but a limit of 2 minutes per individual test.  However, a couple of the tests take a lot longer than this to run, so we tried adding the timeout attribute to the test's declaration, i.e

```
<TestMethod(), Timeout(15 * 60 * 1000)> Public Sub DoSomething()
```

for a 15 minute timeout. However, the 2 minute timeout set in the test run properties seems to be taking precedence, even though it says that the timeout attribute should override it.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the timeout expression with the value, i.e. Timeout(900000).